# Java: Automatic equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` for simple data POJOs is cluttering my code and maintaining is tedious.

What are the libraries handling this automatically?
I prefer bytecode instrumentation over AOP approach due to performance reasons.

**Update:** The topic of the necessity of implementing equals() and hashCode() has been discussed, here's my point:

Isn't it better to have it done right upfront with minimal effort rather than digging in the code, adding hC/eq when it comes to it?

**Edit 2022:** I have switched to Kotlin. Kotlin takes care of most of Java's boilerplate, see this page for the case of `equals()`: https://tedblob.com/kotlin-data-class/

Comment: No library can take care of `equals` for you - only you know what makes two objects equal.  What IDE are you using that doesn't generate `hashCode` for you?  And why are you having to do so much maintenance on `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: I understand that in the Java community it's common to implement these methods for basically every POJO, but I have to ask: are you actually using all of your POJO types as keys in hash tables? Are you comparing them for equality? If not, then why even bother?

Comment: @Paul - NetBeans, and it generates; only, I have to re-generate every time, and also it makes 10's of lines of code. Also, the lib could use reflection when generating, so why couldn't it handle equals?

Comment: @Dan - well, I don't, but various frameworks do - e.g. web frameworks. Keeping track of what instance gets where and when may be difficult in an app with many paradigms used - with all that caching, injection, serialization in components between requests...

Comment: @OndraŽižka: Java's expressiveness is limited by the lack of any declarative distinction between a reference which encapsulates the *state* of an unshared mutable or sharable  immutable object, and one which encapsulates the *identity* of a shared object.  References which are used to encapsulate state should match if the *states* of the identified objects match.  By contrast, those which encapsulate identity should only match if they identify the *same* object.  To define an equivalence relation, one must know the purpose of the things being compared.

Comment: How can you *"prefer bytecode instrumentation over AOP approach"* when AOP is based on bytecode instrumentation? Did you mean compile-time vs load-time instrumentation?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík Yes, I think it's clear from the context: I prefer Lombok way rather than AOP way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) provides the annotation [@EqualsAndHashCode](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) which will generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your Java classes. Of course there are some drawbacks in comparison to manually implementing these methods, so make sure you read the "small print" on the linked page.

Comment: That's probably what I look for. Only pity it's not integrated with NetBeans.

Answer (score 6):

## `Objects.hashCode` & `Objects.hash`

While not the panacea you requested, writing the `hashCode` override is a bit easier now as of Java 7 and later.

As of [Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_7), the [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class offers a couple of utility methods for generating hash code values.

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654058/642706) on a related Question for more discussion.

- If your `hashCode` (and `equals`) override is based on a single member of your class, use [`Objects.hashCode( member )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)).
- If your `hashCode` (and `equals`) override is based on multiple attribute of your class, use [`Objects.hash( memberA , memberB , memberC )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)).

#### Single member, not tolerating a NULL

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.member.hashCode() ;  // Throws NullPointerException if member variable is null.
}
```

#### Single member, tolerating a NULL

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode( this.member ) ;  // Returns zero (0) if `this.member` is NULL, rather than throwing exception.
}
```

#### Multi-member

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash( this.memberA , this.memberB , this.memberC  ) ;  // Hashes the result of all the passed objects’ individual hash codes.  
}
```

---

For an automatically generated `hashCode` & `equals` use a record, as discussed in [my other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72142785/642706).

Answer (score 3):

What about [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Objects.hashCode`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object...)) and [`Objects.equal`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#equal(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))?

Comment: Nah... but thanks for getting me finally check what it's capable of.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google's **[AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value)** library to automatically generate immutable value classes with `equals` and `hashCode`. These value classes are somewhat similar to Scala's case classes or those generated by Lombok.

There's also a [post](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/03/04/using-the-autovalue-code-generator-in-eclipse/) on how to use it in an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache commons-lang library has a HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder that will do some of the work for you and shorten those methods. There are even reflection versions that will do it all for you based on the fields in the POJOs. However, I wouldn't recommend that. Reflection can be slow (though not as bad as many think), and you should implement them to be sure that only the correct fields are considered for equality.

My question is, do you really need to do this? Often hashcode and equals on POJOs only need to be implemented for use with Maps or Sets. In the case of Maps, usually you would use an ID for a key, which isn't the Pojo itself. So, .... are you making work for yourself?

Comment: +1 for 2nd paragraph, but isn't it better to have it done right upfront with minimal effort rather than digging in the code, adding hC/eq when it comes to it?

Comment: Like everything, it ends up being a trade off. It's nice if it's done up front, but implementing it when actually needed hasn't proven overly difficult in my experience. Of course, I usually have tests that tell me when I missed implementing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Records

[Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16) gained a new feature, [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

If the main purpose of your class is to *communicate data transparently and immutably*, write the class as a record.

By default, you need do nothing more than declare the member fields. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record Person ( String givenName , String surname ) {}

record Point ( int x , int y ) {}

record User ( UUID id, String name ) {}
```

The default behavior of a record’s `equals` & `hashCode` is to consider each and every member field. You can override to provide your own logic.

I highly recommend reading the Java JEP linked above. You’ll learn that the purpose of the *record* feature is *not* a reduction in boilerplate. Less code is a nice extra benefit. But if you choose `record` only for  less typing, you’ll likely be abusing the feature. Such abuse may confuse people reading your code, and may lead to other problems.

Comment: Nice. That looks much like Kotlin's `data class`.