# Objects.hash() vs Objects.hashCode(), clarification needed

Tags: hashcode, java-7

Since Java 7, we have

```
o.hashCode();
Objects.hashCode(o);
Objects.hash(o);
```

The first two are roughly the same with the null check, but what is last one?

> When a single object reference is supplied, the returned value does
> not equal the hash code of that object reference.

Why is that? I mean, we don't need three methods that do the same thing, I understand that, but why do we need `Objects.hash()` at all? When would you chose to use one over another?

Answer (score 100):

See the documentation for [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hash`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29).  `hash` takes `Object...` while `hashCode` takes `Object`.  The example given is:

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y, z);
}
```

- `Objects.hash(Object... values)` should be used in cases when you want a hash of a sequence of objects, e.g. when defining your own `hashCode` method and want a simply-coded hash for multiple values that make up the identity of your object.
- `Objects.hashCode(Object o)` should be used when you want the hash of a single object, without throwing if the object is null.
- `Object::hashCode()` should be used when you want the hash of a single object, and will throw an exception if the object is null.

Note that `hash(o)` and `hashCode(o)` won't necessarily return the same thing!  If you're doing it for a single object, you should probably use `hashCode`.

Comment: In what situation would `hash(o)` and `hashCode(o)` not return the same value? The docs for `hash()` state `Warning: When a single object reference is supplied, the returned value does not equal the hash code of that object reference.`, but I'm still digging to figure out why.

Comment: @CraigOtis `Objects.hash` just calls `Arrays.hashCode` (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java#l145) and the `hashCode` of a single object is different from the `hashCode` of an array with that single object in it (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l4677)

Comment: Thanks @PeterHull, that makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 46):

## `Objects.hashCode`

The utility method [`Objects.hashCode( Object o )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)) simply calls the `hashCode` method on the passed object.

### Tolerates NULL

So why invent or use this method? Why not just call the object’s `hashCode` method yourself?

This method offers one benefit: `NULL` ➙ `0`. The utility method tolerates a null.

- If you call `Objects.hashCode( myObject )` where `myObject` is `NULL`, you get back a zero (0).
- In contrast, calling `myObject.hashCode()` when `myObject` is `NULL` throws a `NullPointerException` argument.

Whether tolerating a null is desirable or not depends on your own judgement in your particular situation.

## `Objects.hash`

The utility method [`Objects.hash( Object o , … )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)) serves a different purpose. This method has two phases:

- Call `.hashCode` on each passed object, collecting each result.
- Calculate a hash on the collected results.

### hash of a hash

If you pass a single object, `Objects.hash( myObject )`, first `myObject.hashCode` is called and collected, and then a hash on that single-item collection is calculated. So, you end up with a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of a hash.

When hashing a single object, it is vital to understand that `Objects.hashCode( myObject )` returns a different result than `Objects.hash( myObject )`. Effectively, the second returns a hash on the result of the first.

## Annoying in practice

The logic of the approach taken in these two `Objects` methods makes sense, in and of themselves.

Unfortunately, in practice, for those of us trying to use them in day-to-day use when writing code on our POJOs to override `hashCode`, and correspondingly `equals`, we must think twice to decide which to call.

- If your `hashCode` (and `equals`) override is based on a single member of your class, use `Objects.hashCode( member )`.
- If your `hashCode` (and `equals`) override is based on multiple attribute of your class, use `Objects.hash( memberA , memberB , memberC )`.

### Single member, not tolerating a NULL

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.member.hashCode() ;  // Throws NullPointerException if member variable is null.
}
```

### Single member, tolerating a NULL

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode( this.member ) ;  // Returns zero (0) if `this.member` is NULL, rather than throwing exception.
}
```

### Multi-member, tolerating a NULL

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash( this.memberA , this.memberB , this.memberC  ) ;  // Hashes the result of all the passed objects’ individual hash codes.  
}
```

## Example

We can test these various methods quite simply.

### UUID

Let's use a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) object as an example. A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (*universally unique identifier*) is a 128-bit value where certain bits have certain semantics.

The *OpenJDK* implementation of `UUID` internally represents the 128-bit value as a pair of 64-bit `long` integer numbers.

That same implementation overrides `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` to look at the data stored in that pair of long integers. Here is the [source code for those two methods](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java).

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ((null == obj) || (obj.getClass() != UUID.class))
        return false;
    UUID id = (UUID)obj;
    return (mostSigBits == id.mostSigBits &&
            leastSigBits == id.leastSigBits);
}
```

```java
public int hashCode() {
    long hilo = mostSigBits ^ leastSigBits;
    return ((int)(hilo >> 32)) ^ (int) hilo;
}
```

### Example code

Instantiate our UUID object.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Calculate our hash values.

```
int hash1 = uuid.hashCode();
int hash2 = Objects.hashCode( uuid );  // Result matches line above.

int hash3 = Objects.hash( uuid );  // Returns a hash of a hash.
int hash4 = Objects.hash( uuid.hashCode() ); // Result matches line above.
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "uuid.toString(): " + uuid.toString() );
System.out.println( " 1/2 = " + hash1 + " | " + hash2 );
System.out.println( " 3/4 = " + hash3 + " | " + hash4 );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/kQKYh7).

> uuid.toString(): 401d88ff-c75d-4607-bb89-1f7a2c6963e1
>
> 1/2 = 278966883 | 278966883
>
> 3/4 = 278966914 | 278966914

Answer (score 15):

The default hashCode() of Object returns the memory address for the object. So if you have the following class:

```
class Car {
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;

    public Car(String make, String model, int year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

then create two objects:

```
Car car1 = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", 2010);
Car car2 = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla", 2010);
```

car1.hashCode() will be different from car2.hashCode() because each object will have a different memory address.

What if you want both car1 and car2 to return the same hash code? In this case, you should override the default Object hashCode() method for the Car class as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    Object[] x = {model, make, Integer.valueOf(year)};
    int hashArray = Arrays.hashCode(x);
    return hashArray;
}
```

This will make car1.hashCode() equal to car2.hashCode() because the String.hashCode() calculates the hashCode based on the string contents, and the Integer.hashCode() will return the integer value itself.

In Java 7, you can just use Objects.hash(Object... values). So our new Car hashCode() will look as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(model, make, year);
}
```

Objects.hash(Object... values) will call Arrays.hashCode for you.

Finally, Objects.hashCode(Object o) will do a null check. It will return 0 if the object is null. Else, it will call the objects hashCode() method.

Comment: The default `hashCode()` hasn't returned the memory address for about 20 years. It can't really. GC moves objects around. The so-called memory address is that of an umoveable handle.

Comment: Based on the Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode

The hashCode "is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language."

Comment: @ezzadeen Perhaps it would help to change the wording from “returns the memory address” to “returns something akin to the memory address”.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java

```
public static int hashCode(Object o) {
    return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
}

public static int hash(Object... values) {
    return Arrays.hashCode(values);
}
```

Mystery solved :D

For extra clarity the `Arrays.hashCode` has different implementations for different types. For example Object's is:

```
public static int hashCode(Object a[]) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 1;

    for (Object element : a)
        result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

    return result;
}
```

Since `a` is of type `Object` the `element.hashCode()` would call `Object.hashCode` **which is the same as used above in `Objects.hashCode()`**.

But what is exactly under the hood? Not easy to answer as this maps to `JVM_IHashCode` which is defined in https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp as `ObjectSynchronizer::FastHashCode` (sorry for jumping between java versions... to C++).

Now you know what is the C++ implementation of the 2 JAVA methods :D at least for the OpenJDK.