# Override hashCode() of Graphstream

Tags: java, graphstream

How do I override the hashCode() of the Graphstream Node object?

I am inserting the Nodes into a HashSet.

`HashSet<Node> set = new HashSet<Node>();`

Comment: Well, there are multiple Nodes with the same hash.

Comment: Write a wrapper class for `Node` and provide implementations for `hashCode` and `equals` there. Then use a `Set` of that type instead of `Node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may inherit from Node to extend the objects hash in this class using *Objects.hash(Object...)*. Just throw into this method whatever you want to have hashed together ...

```
class MyNode extends Node {

// whatever floats you boat here

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), other);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // hashCode() and equals() overrides should always appear together
    }
}
```

Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597386/objects-hash-vs-objects-hashcode-clarification-needed)

EDIT: Dont' forget the equals() override!