# Comparing objects and its member variable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, compare

Suppose I have two objects of same class for example:

```
public class Example {
    String name;
    String rollNo;
    String address;
    String phoneNo;
    String city;
}

Example obj1 = new Example();
    obj1.name = "Name";
    obj1.rollNo = "10";
    obj1.address = "Address";
    obj1.phoneNo = "Phone Number";
    obj1.city = "City";

Example obj2 = new Example();
    obj2.name = "Name";
    obj2.rollNo = "10";
    obj2.address = "Address";
    obj2.phoneNo = "Phone Number";
    obj2.city = "City";
```

Here I want to compare `obj1` with `obj2` the catch is I don't want to do this with if condition i.e. getting each member variable of `obj1` then comparing it with `obj2` variable.

`equals` method of `java.lang.Object` class will not work here as it compares object reference.

My question is, is there any Java API which will compare two objects and its member variables.

Comment: you have to override equals in your example class.

Comment: You can override the equals method.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but overriding will not solve my problem. Actually I am looking for Java API which will do this.

Comment: 'overriding will not solve my problem'. Why not? What do you need from an API that can't be done by overriding `equals`?

Comment: Actually @PakkuDon if I override `equals` method then I will have to write if conditions, what if there are 20 member variable in a class then I will have to write 20 `if` condition, actually I want to avoid `if` conditions.

Comment: You could let eclipse auto generate it or you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959307/java-automatic-equals-and-hashcode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Example other = (Example) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (phoneNo == null) {
            if (other.phoneNo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!phoneNo.equals(other.phoneNo))
            return false;
        if (rollNo == null) {
            if (other.rollNo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!rollNo.equals(other.rollNo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Paste this equals function into your exmaple class and then compare the objects like this:

```
 if(obj1.equals(obj2)) {  //will return true now

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Kai, actually problem statement remains same, I am looking for some Java API, suppose my member variable increases then I will have to write more `if` condition, that actually I want to avoid.

Comment: there is no api. you cant avoid an if condition for every single member. there is only an api which updates the equals method when you add an new member.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there is three alternatives to compare objects :

1. By overriding the Object.equals() method.
2. Using the Generic [java.util.Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) Interface
3. Using the [java.lang.Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344246/comparator-and-equals), and [this](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) link for more details.