# Getting an "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'int'" error and I'm unsure why

Tags: java, if-statement, intellij-idea

I'm writing a method that is to determine if two "Course" objects, where a "Course" object is comprised of  courseName (String), department (String), code (int), section (byte), and instructor (String), and returns "true" if the objects have equivalent values. However, in the portion of the method that checks if they original "Course" object and the new "Course" object are equal, I am getting the above error.

Code for reference:

```
public boolean equals(Course obj){
    if(obj instanceof Course){

        Course c = (Course)obj;

        if(this.courseName.equals(course.getName()) &&
                this.department.equals(course.getDepartment()) &&
                (this.code==course.getCode()) &&
                (Byte.compare(this.section, course.getSection())) &&
                this.instructor.equals(course.getInstructor()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Error is listed as being on the line `if(this.courseName.equals(course.getName()) &&`, but I'm unsure if it's referring to the entire if statement.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `(Byte.compare(this.section, course.getSection()))`? Do you want to compare less than or greater than?

Comment: You also wrote Course instead of Object for the argument type. Use a tool that can generate equals for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959307/java-automatic-equals-and-hashcode

Comment: There's also a mismatch between your `Course c` variable and the subsequent use of the `course` variable.

Comment: Byte.compare returns an int value. 0 in case if both values are equal so ...`(Byte.compare(this.section, course.getSection()) == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

The error is referring to the entire `if` statement. `Byte.compare()` returns an `int`, which cannot be used with logical operators.

For primitive `byte` values, you can just use `==`:

```
if(this.courseName.equals(course.getName()) &&
        this.department.equals(course.getDepartment()) &&
        this.code == course.getCode() &&
        this.section == course.getSection() &&
        this.instructor.equals(course.getInstructor())) {
   
    return true;
}
```

Also note that you have a `NullPointerException` risk in your string comparisons.